# position a fixed element inside a container

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a fixed #listMDMap element that I want to position inside the div with class "row"

```
           <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="row">
                <div id="listMDMap" [style.position]="'fixed'" [style.top.px]="computeMapTopForFixedPosition()"  class="col-md-12" [style.height.px]="computeMapMDHeight()" >
                  <agm-map #gm [latitude]="mainLatitude" [longitude]="mainLongitude" [style.height.px]="computeMapMDHeight()" [fitBounds]="true">
..................
..................
                  </agm-map>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

How to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did it specifying for my "#listMDMap" top, left, width, height=width of the parent ".row"

Answer (score 0):

You basically can't position a fixed element, relative to its parent. What you can do is set the childs `position` to `sticky`, which has some properties of `position: fixed`.
Otherwise you could of course use `position: absolute` on the child and `position: relative` on its parent.